# What are the standard math prerequisites for physical chemistry?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm currently a chemistry major and I know that physical chemistry requires lots of calculus.  Which mathematics courses should I take so that I am well prepared for my physical chemistry courses? Specifically, I need to take courses in thermodynamics, quantum chemistry and statistical thermodynamics and beyond, as I want to specialize in physical chemistry.

Is it true that the more mathematics courses that one takes, the easier physical chemistry becomes? I'm currently taking a multivariate calculus course now, and I wonder which is the next level of math courses I should take.

I plan to take as many mathematics courses as possible. I'm thinking of taking ordinary differential equations after i finish multivariate calculus. What additional courses beyond ordinary differential equations should I take? My school offers courses in complex analysis, real analysis, and partial differential equations. Will they be useful?

Comment: consider: for quantum mechanics: linear algebra, function approximation, Fourier series and transforms, numerical methods (eigenvalue problem, integration, error estimation) for statistical thermodynamics: series summation.

Comment: Well my school offer ODE, real analysis, Complex analysis and PDE. Will they be useful?

Comment: Hm. Take all of them, maybe except complex analysis (it is not absolutely necessary, but you need concept of a complex number for QC. you don't, however, need to concern yourself with deep analysis of functions of complex argument, but it sometimes suddenly useful in integration of ordinary functions). Search for linear algebra and numerical methods books. The topics are quite simple in nature and may be self-taught, since you don't have to work within - only to apply them.

Comment: I got through statistical thermodynamics with calc 3 and linear algebra alone. But it was tough. Diff. Eq. should be helpful for that class, but in my experience if you have a decent math background ( calc 1, 2, 3 ) you can usually get enough guidance to survive the physical chemistry courses even if you don't have the exact math training. If you plan on doing physical chemistry professionally, learn all the math you can.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the most helpful advanced math courses you can take for Physical Chemistry are Differential Equations and Linear Algebra. Multivariate Calculus is helpful, but not as helpful as Diff. Eq. would be, especially in the beginning. Linear Algebra is very helpful for quantum chemistry, Diff. Eq. is also helpful for quantum, but more so for statistical mechanics. In the comments you mentioned several different Diff. Eq. options - as @permeakra said, taking all of them is a good idea, but ODEs and PDEs will probably be the most useful.

Comment: How about Complex and real analysis? In my school though, the prerequisite for PDE is real analysis. That means i have to take real analysis before i can take PDE.

Comment: Well, then I guess you need to take it ;). I can tell you that you will definitely be solving PDEs in chemical thermodynamics, quantum mechanics, and statistical mechanics. I'm actually a little surprised that these aren't prerequisites for Physical Chemistry courses in your program, in schools I am familiar with (I'm in the U.S.) "Differential Equations" gives an overview of all of this - maybe the courses at your school go more in-depth?

Comment: My undergrad only required calc II for p-chem, and I was taking calc III the same semester as p-chem, it was much harder to understand some of the math. But I think the math department was tired of having classes mostly full of chemistry majors.